Issue en amchart5, Next js
Tengo este componente en el que muestro un mapa, con datos dinamicos, para mostrar estos datos en el pais correcto hago el setData, el problema es que tambien quiero al hacer click hacer una funcion que haga cambios en otro componente, que eso ya lo tengo resuelto, el inconveniente es cuando agrego estos datos, los paises con la informacion dinamica no me devuelven el id, o no responden al evento click que cambia el estado del otro componente, si alguno tiene la respuesta muchas gracias, saludos
useLayoutEffect(() => {
      // Crear el root del mapa
      const root = am5.Root.new('chartdiv');

      // Establecer temas
      root.setThemes([am5themes_Animated.new(root)]);

      // Crear el chart de mapa
      const chart = root.container.children.push(
         am5map.MapChart.new(root, {
            panX: 'translateX',
            panY: 'translateY',
            projection: am5map.geoMercator(),
         })
      );

      // Crear la serie de polígonos
      const polygonSeries = chart.series.push(
         am5map.MapPolygonSeries.new(root, {
            geoJSON: am5geodata_region_world_southAmericaLow,
         })
      );

      polygonSeries.data.setAll(
         data.map((country) => ({
            id: country?.country_key,
            narrative: Object.entries(country?.operators)
               .map(([operatorName, operatorData]) => {
                  const validBands = Object.entries(operatorData.radio)
                     .filter(([band, value]) => value > 0)
                     .map(([band]) => band.toUpperCase())
                     .join(', ');

                  return validBands
                     ? `<strong> ${operatorName}:<br /> ${validBands}</strong>`
                     : null;
               })
               .filter((detail) => detail !== null)
               .join('<br/>'),
         }))
      );

      // Configurar los estilos de los
      polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.setAll({
         tooltipHTML: '<div><b>{name}<br/></b><p>{narrative}</p></div>',
         toggleKey: 'active',
         fill: am5.color(0x252627),
      });

      polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.events.on('click', (ev) => {
         const clickedCountryId = ev.target.dataItem.get('id');
         console.log(clickedCountryId);

         handleCountryChange({ target: { value: clickedCountryId } });
      });

      polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.states.create('hover', {
         fill: am5.color(0xbacf00),
      });

      /* polygonSeries.mapPolygons.template.states.create('active', {
         fill: am5.color(0xbacf00),
      }); */

      // Añadir control de zoom
      /* const zoomControl = chart.set(
         'zoomControl',
         am5map.ZoomControl.new(root, {})
      );
      zoomControl.homeButton.set('visible', true); */

      chart.chartContainer.get('background').events.on('click', () => {
         chart.goHome();
      });

      chart.appear(1000, 100);

      return () => {
         root.dispose();
      };
   }, [data]);

